# asp.net mvc3 Bind Exclude on properties does not work

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a class, which has 8 properties / 8 columns in DB. In the Edit page, I want to exclude the AddedDate and UserID fields. When a user edits a voucher, he can't overwrite the AddedDate or UserID values in the DB.

```
public class Voucher
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string SiteName { get; set; }
    public string DealURL { get; set; }
    public DateTime AddedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ExpirationDate { get; set; }
    public string VoucherFileURL { get; set; }
    public Guid UserID { get; set; }
}
```

Here is what I have for Edit controller:

```
// POST: /Voucher/Edit/5

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Exclude = "AddedDate")]Voucher voucher)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

        db.Entry(voucher).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(voucher);
}
```

On Edit page, when I click on submit, I got the following error:

```
System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException: An overflow occurred while converting to datetime.
```

Seems like the AddedDate didn't get excluded from the voucher object and triggered the error.

Would you please let me know how to fix it? Thanks!

(it is an updated version of [asp.net mvc3 UpdateModel exclude properties is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9747165/asp-net-mvc3-updatemodel-exclude-properties-is-not-working), I will go with another approach)

Comment: Please do not bind directly to your entities if security is a concern for you.

Comment: How do you know the error is not from ExpirationDate ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never use your domain entities as action arguments and never pass your domain entities to your views. I would recommend you to use view models. In the view model you will include only the properties that you want to be bound from the view. The view model is a class that's specifically tailored to the requirements of a given view.

```
public class VoucherViewModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string SiteName { get; set; }
    public string DealURL { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ExpirationDate { get; set; }
    public string VoucherFileURL { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(VoucherViewModel model)
{
    // TODO: if the view model is valid map it to a model
    // and pass the model to your DAL
    // To ease the mapping between your models and view models
    // you could use a tool such as AutoMapper: http://automapper.org/
    ...
}
```

---

UPDATE:

In the comments section @Rick.Anderson-at-Microsoft.com points out that while I have answered your question I haven't explained where the problem comes from.

The thing is that `DateTime` is a value type meaning it will always have a value. The `[Bind(Exclude = "AddedDate")]` works perfectly fine and it does what it is supposed to do => it doesn't bind the `AddedDate` property from the request. As a consequence the property will have its default value which for a DateTime field is `1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM` and when he attempts to save this in SQL Server it blows because SQL Server doesn't support such format.

Comment: This is the best answer but still does't explain why bind exclude failed. My guess is it's not the dateTime he thinks it is.

Comment: @Rick.Anderson-at-Microsoft.com, no. It's because `DateTime` is a value type meaning it will always have a value. The `[Bind(Exclude = "AddedDate")]` works perfectly fine and it does what it is supposed to do => it doesn't bind the AddedDate property from the request. As a consequence the property will have its default value which is `1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM` and when he attempts to save this in SQL Server it blows because SQL Server doesn't support such format. Thanks for pointing this out. I have updated my answer to include this information.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I can't edit my first comment to change the font to strike through.

Comment: What if I want some property in my ViewModel, but do not want it to get updated, should I be using Bind Exclude?

Comment: @Narayana, what would be the purpose of such property? How and who will assign it a value? Maybe you could make it with a private setter or something. It would really depend on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I've a CustomerId which is generated based on some logic while creating a customer. I want to show it on the read/edit screens, but users should not edit it. I will of course prevent editing it on the client side, but it is a property that is in the ViewModel. How do I prevent a hacked-edit? I use Automapper if there's some easy way there.

Comment: @Narayana, you could have 2 view models. One without the property and and one that derives from it and adds the property. The first will be used as parameter to your POST controller action and the second will be passed to the view.

Comment: Oh. Never thought like that. Its seems the most straight forward way, since these scenarios are not common. Thanks!